# Ubuntu unable to reach Router

Tags: wireless, internet

Good morning,
I've installed Qimo few days back and have issues connecting to the internet (it works for a few seconds when I reboot). I am able to connect to my Wireless Network using automatic or manual configuration of the network and Ubuntu state that I am connected. My Router also show my computer as connected. However, I am unable to open any website or do updates.

When I run `ping 192.168.0.1` (IP of my router) I get an "Unreachable" message.

I run the wireless script which is proposed in some previous comments. The content can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9768480/

Any ideas where the problem can be ?

Comment: Is your router set to respond to pings? And is it set to allow your computer access?

Comment: It is, I have 4 devises connected to the router, a Windows computer, a Skype phone, a Symbian devise and the Ubuntu Computer(which also contains a perfectly working windows installation). I can ping without problems from windows and all devises work except when I run Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You're using this Qimo - [Qimo 4 Kids](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=qimo)? According to distrowatch it doesn't appear to  have been updated for about 5 years (May 2010), it (or it's kernel) might not be able to use your wireless hardware properly (I had a little wifi adapter that would "pretend to connect" but couldn't even get an address/dhcp info).

I don't know if updating it would be possible, if it's based on Ubuntu 10.04 it was a LTS release, but the desktop version was only supported until 9 May 2013, the server version is supported for another 3 months (until April 2015) so an update *might* be possible?

But it might be more up-to-date to take a current Ubuntu (maybe Xubuntu or even Linux Mint XFCE) and install the programs that you'd like, reading them from the current Qimo's program menus, or it's installed packages (but there's dozens of packages that aren't the main programs) [ [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) ]. The screenshot looks like it uses Docky or Cairo Dock for the bottom menu, fyi.